# How to move comments form above comments list in wordpress

Tags: comments

Please help me modify code to move Comments form above comments list in a WordPress blow. Below is the code of `comments.php` page

```
 <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 */
?>

<?php
    /*
     * If the current post is protected by a password and
     * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
     * return early without loading the comments.
     */
    if (post_password_required()) return;
?>
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
    <div id="comments" class="comments-area clear-fix">
            <?php if (have_comments()):?>
            <div class="comments-area-title">
                <h3>
                    <?php printf( _n('1 comment', '%1$s comments', get_comments_number(), 'gloria'),  number_format_i18n(get_comments_number()));?>
                </h3>
            </div><!-- End Comment Area Title -->
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>
            <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
            <ol class="commentlist">
                <?php
                    /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
                     * to use wpgrade_comment() to format the comments.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then you can
                     * define wpgrade_comment() and that will be used instead.
                     * See wpgrade_comment() in inc/template-tags.php for more.
                     */
                    wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'gloria_comments','short_ping'  => true ) );
                ?>
            </ol><!-- .commentlist -->

            <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
            <nav role="navigation" id="comment-nav-bottom" class="comment-navigation clearfix">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( '&larr; Older Comments', 'gloria' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'gloria' ) ); ?></div>
            </nav>
            <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>
        <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>
        <?php
            // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
            if ( ! comments_open() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) && !is_page() ) :
        ?>
            <p class="nocomments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'gloria' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->
    <?php
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $comments_args = array(
            // change the title of send button
            'title_reply'=> esc_html__('Leave a reply', 'gloria'),
            // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
            'comment_notes_before' => '',
            'comment_notes_after' => '',
            'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Logged in as', 'gloria') .' <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="'.esc_html__('Log out of this account','gloria').'">'.esc_html__('Log out?','gloria').'</a>', admin_url( 'profile.php' ), $user_identity, wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>',            
            'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(
                'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="'.esc_html__('Name*', 'gloria').'..." size="30" ' .  $aria_req . ' /></p>',
                'email' => '<p class="comment-form-email"><input id="email" name="email" size="30" type="text" placeholder="'.esc_html__('Email*', 'gloria').'..." '. $aria_req .' /></p>' ) ),
            'id_submit' => 'comment-submit',
            'label_submit' => esc_html__('Send', 'gloria'),
            // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
            'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Message', 'gloria' ) . '"></textarea></p>');
    } else {
        $comments_args = array(
        // change the title of send button
        'title_reply'=> esc_html__('Leave a reply', 'gloria'),
        // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
        'comment_notes_before' => '',
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(
                'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="'.esc_html__('Name*', 'gloria').'..." size="30" ' .  $aria_req . ' /></p><!--',
                'email' => '--><p class="comment-form-email"><input id="email" name="email" size="30" type="text" placeholder="'.esc_html__('Email*', 'gloria').'..." '. $aria_req .' /></p><!--',
                'url' => '--><p class="comment-form-url"><input id="url" name="url" size="30" placeholder="'.esc_html__('Website', 'gloria').'..." type="text"></p>') ),
        'id_submit' => 'comment-submit',
        'label_submit' => esc_html__('Send', 'gloria'),
        // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Message', 'gloria' ) . '"></textarea></p>');
    }

    //if we have no comments than we don't a second title, one is enough
    if ( !have_comments() ){
        $comments_args['title_reply'] = esc_html__('Leave a reply', 'gloria');
    }

    comment_form($comments_args); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If the answer worked please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `if (have_comments()) { ... }` checks whether there is any comment on your post, and starts a loop to display them.

The `comment_form()` function is responsible to render the comment form. So, if you want to swap their positions, you should swap these two.

But, you should make sure you move both `comment_form()` and its arguments (`$comments_args`) above the comment loop, since this variable should be defined first, or the default fields will be used.

The easy way to do this is to select the entire `<div id="comments" class="comments-area clear-fix">...</div>`, cut it and paste of below the `comment_form()`. Pay attention to PHP open and close tags `<?php` & `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the comments template file (comments.php) so that the **comment_form() function** is called *before* the comments list, which then will move the comments form above the comments list.

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
    <div id="comments" class="comments-area clear-fix">
        <?php // Move the comments form above the comments list ?>
        <?php comment_form(); ?>
        <?php if (have_comments()):?>
        <div class="comments-area-title">
            <h3>
                <?php printf( _n('1 comment', '%1$s comments', get_comments_number(), 'gloria'),  number_format_i18n(get_comments_number()));?>
            </h3>
        </div><!-- End Comment Area Title -->
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>
        <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
                 * to use wpgrade_comment() to format the comments.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then you can
                 * define wpgrade_comment() and that will be used instead.
                 * See wpgrade_comment() in inc/template-tags.php for more.
                 */
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'gloria_comments','short_ping'  => true ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav role="navigation" id="comment-nav-bottom" class="comment-navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( '&larr; Older Comments', 'gloria' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'gloria' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>
    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>
    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) && !is_page() ) :
    ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'gloria' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->
    <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
```